# StubObserver: How to verify if stub method is called with the right paramerter?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

i refer to this article from Peter Provost:

[Visual Studio 2012 Fakes - Part 3 - Observing Stub Behavior](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/11/29/visual-studio-2012-fakes-part-3/)

The question is if and how can i verify if the method is called with a defined parameter? For example somthing like that:

```
var wasCalled = observer.GetCalls().Any(call => call.StubbedMethod.Name == methodName && call.StubMethod.Parameter == "Hello there!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

var wasCalled = observer.GetCalls().Any(call => call.StubbedMethod.Name == methodName && (string)call.GetArguments() == "Hello there!");

HTH
Patrick Tseng
Microsoft ALM team